# Error: java: package org.springframework.boot.loader does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I know this type of question has been asked before but I've searched a few answers so far and nothing successful. I am trying to use the following dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-loader -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

However I'm getting an error with the following when running:
[image]
[image]

I've tried re importing all maven projects, download sources and generating sources but with no success. Does anyone know what it might be?

Comment: try without `<scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: Because it's not run-scope, when you run your application, the jar won't be available.The `<scope>provided</scope>` is for just Build and test purpose.